# checking for an empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get an empty input if there is one in my div using jQuery.  It is not working as it should.

There are 4 empty inputs in the div.

Here is my jquery:

```
var firstEmpty = $('#brochureItems').find('input:text:not(:checkbox,:button):visible:first:enabled[value= ""]').first().val();
console.log(firstEmpty);
```

That outputs 'undefined'.

When I remove the "[value=""]", I get '(an empty string)' outputted.

I just thought of something, I am adding those inputs in dynamically with jquery on page load.  Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Could you provide your html that you are traversing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you want to get all empty inputs inside a div. To do so, try this code:

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text" value="asdsad">
</div>
```

JS

```
var firstEmpty = $("div input[type='text']").filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; });
```

or if you want take all empty:

```
var emptyInputs = [];

$("div input[type='text']").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    emptyInputs.push($(this))
});
```

Here is working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xs9jagc8/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
function findEmpty(){
  var div=document.getElementById('theDivID');
  for(var i=0;i<div.children.length;i++){
    if(div.children[i].value==''){
      return div.children[i].id;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
function verify(){
  var lol = findEmpty();
  if(lol===false){
    //Do whatever
    alert("All filled!");
  } else {
    alert("The first empty input is: "+lol);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='theDivID'>
<input id='blah' type='text'/>
<input id='bleh' type='text'/>
<input id='qwertyuiop' type='text'/>
<input type='text'/>
</div>
<input type='button' onclick='verify();' value='Check'/>
```

Comment: It's pure js but he needs a jquery workaround.

Comment: If he can use JQuery, he can use pure JS.